# Convert mysql query with left join into Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a mysql query like this:

```
select result.*, rank_text.text
from  cache_user_challenge_result result
left join rank_text on result.rank
between rank_text.rank_from and rank_text.rank_to
```

Now I want to change this to eloquent for my laravel project, I tried this but it's not work:

```
$this->select(
                        "{$this->table}.user_id",
                        'rank_text.text'
                    )
                    ->leftJoin('rank_text', "{$this->table}.rank")
                    ->whereBetween("{$this->table}.rank", ['rank_text.rankFrom', 'rank_text.rankTo'])
                    ->first();
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

Thank you very much!

Update:

After a lot of hours, I change my query to this:

```
$this->select(
                        "{$this->table}.user_id",
                        'rank_text.text'
                    )
                    ->leftJoin('rank_text', function($query) {
                        $query->whereBetween("{$this->table}.rank", ['rank_text.rank_from', 'rank_text.rank_to']);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

But it's only can get user_id, not the text.

Comment: What does `$this` refer to?

Comment: it's refer to my table, problem only with my query

Comment: I doubt `$this->select()` does not work. It should either be replaced with `DB query builder` or `Eloquent` model.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create cache_user_challenge_result model Like

```
class CacheUserChallengeResult extends Model {
    protected $table = 'cache_user_challenge_result';
    public function scopeGetCacheUserRank()
    {
       return static::select(DB::raw('cache_user_challenge_result.*,rank_text.text'))->leftJoin('rank_text', function($join) {
  $join->on('cache_user_challenge_result..rank', '=', 'rank_text.rank')->whereBetween('cache_user_challenge_result.rank',['rank_text.rankFrom', 'rank_text.rankTo']);
});
    }
 }
```

In Controller You can call like this

```
CacheUserChallengeResult::getCacheUserRank()->get();
```

It will provide you the collection for the rank you desire, also you can pass param for which rank you want in range